# Android App Link not working when apps are installed on "Work" profile

Tags: android, applinks, xiaomi, android-enterprise

I have two mobile apps that need to communicate via Android App Links (let's say Mobile App A must invoke Mobile App B). Both mobile apps are installed in the "Work" profile area (Android Enteprise).

The expected UX is that when App A invoke App B, App B asks for credentials and after that, it should redirect the user to App A.

What happens, instead, is that App B does not redirect to App A after credentials, but it opens Chrome (without even open the disambiguation dialog).

Analyzing the logs when the app A is installed, I can see that the link verification passed:

```
11-18 14:07:42.892 26837  3063 I IntentFilterIntentOp: Verifying IntentFilter. verificationId:37 scheme:"https" hosts:"domain.example.com"
11-18 14:07:43.813 26837  3063 I IntentFilterIntentOp: Verification 37 complete. Success:true. Failed hosts:. [CONTEXT service_id=244 ]
```

But when I type the command *adb shell dumpsys package domain-preferred-apps*, I see the following output for App A:

```
Package: it.example.com
Domains: domain.example.com
Status:  undefined
```

The *assetlinks.json* file is correctly hosted on domain.example.com, in fact this whole App Link mechanism works when both apps are installed outside "Work" profile.

Does App Links work with app installed inside "Work" profiles or there are some restrictions?

*UPDATE*:
It seems that this problem occurs on Xiaomi devices.

Answer (score 0):

Google confirmed that it is a bug with Android < 12.

Follows the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/224564038